# Find the probability that the product of three random integers is divisible by 100.

Tags: probability

Find the probability that the product of three random integers is divisible by 100.

How to approach ? How to know the sample space in this case ?

[image]

Image of exact question

Comment: Unless you are told the sample space and the associated probabilities, there is no way to do the problem.  I would guess that they mean the integers to be chosen uniformly at random from $1,2,3\dots,100,$ but that's only a guess.

Comment: This was exactly the question . Only difference was the use of word chances instead of probability .

Comment: Yes, since they haven't told you what they mean by a "random integer" there is no way to really answer the question.  There isn't a generally agreed-upon probability distribution for the integers.  You can make a guess at what is meant and answer that question.  If this is a homework problem, and there's no chance of asking the teacher, I would guess, and write a note explaining what I did.

Comment: Not a homework problem. Kind of a quiz question posted by codechef .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that a plausible answer can be found, making some sensible assumptions.  In particular we'll assume that the uniform sample is chosen so that, say, the probability that a randomly chosen integer is even is exactly $\frac 12$ (or close enough) and so on.

To be divisible by $100$ a number must be divisible by $4$ and by $25$.  These conditions are independent.

Let's start with $4$.  The only ways the product could fail to be divisible by $4$ are to have all of them odd, or exactly one of them even but not divisible by $4$.  The probability that a randomly selected integer (however, sensibly, defined) is odd is $\frac 12$.  Thus the probability that all three are odd is $\frac 18$.  The probability that a randomly selected integer is even but not divisible by $4$ is $\frac 14$ so the probability that exactly one of the three is such is $3\times \frac 14\times \frac 12\times \frac 12=\frac 3{16}$.  It follows that the probability that our product is divisible by $4$ is $$1-\frac 18-\frac 3{16}=\frac {11}{16}$$

The case of $25$ is similar. The probability that a randomly selected integer (however, sensibly, defined) is not divisible by $5$ is $\frac 45$.  Thus the probability that none of the three is divisible by $5$ is $\left(\frac 45\right)^3$.  The probability that a randomly selected integer is divisible by $5$ but not divisible by $25$ is $\frac 4{25}$ (since there are exactly $4$ residue classes $\mod {25}$ that are $0\pmod 5$ but not $0\pmod {25}$). so the probability that exactly one of the three is such is $3\times \frac 4{25}\times \frac 45\times \frac 45$.   The final result is $$1-\left(\frac 45\right)^3-3\times \frac 4{25}\times \left(\frac 45\right)^2=\frac {113}{625}$$

The desired answer is then the product:  $$\boxed {\frac {11}{16}\times \frac {113}{625}= .1243}$$

Comment: Please explain the 25 case

Comment: It's exactly parallel to the $4$ case.  I'll edit my solution to add more detail.

Comment: Thanks . I got it .

Comment: Was it intentional to use $\approx$ even when the product is exactly $.1243$? :)

Comment: @ErickWong  Nope, force of habit!  Thanks for pointing it out (now edited).